# Distance Sensor placement of resistor

Tags: raspbian

I am a noob and have a question about the distance sensor circuit.

[image]

Why is the resistor in the red rectange even there? What is the purpose of this resostor? I see it is in connected with the GP17 but why is there the 330Ω and 470Ω resistor in one line and the 330Ω resistor connected to the grounder? Shouldn't the electricity go the way with the smallest resistance and go directly to the grounder then? Why is this even working?

Source: https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/physical-computing-with-python/distance/

Thank you very much and kind regards,
SirSandmann

Answer (score 1):

That resistor, in combination with the one adjacent to it form a "voltage divider". What this does is when the circuit is HIGH, the voltage 'splits' between the GPIO pin and ground, through the resistors.

It's a way to lower the voltage going to the 3.3v GPIO pin from the 5v input coming from the sensor, to protect the Pi from damage.

For all the fun math associated with how voltage/potential dividers work, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider).

Answer (score -1):

**Thevenin's theorem**:  Vgpio = +5V * Rbottom / (Rtop + Rbottom)
Where Rbottom is the Resistor going from the GPIO pin node to ground, and Rtop is going from +5V to the GPIO pin node.  Do the math.

Comment: You don't understand Thevenin's theorem. Neither does this answer the question.